# How to commit dataset changes without write to database in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

There is a dataset in which changes are made. These changes are already stored in the database from other code. 
How to do something like DataSet.AcceptChanges() without writing to DB ?

Comment: The question cannot be answered as it is. Show some related code and further state your actual problem. What is the purpose of accepting/committing changes unless you want to persist the data?

Comment: There are some actions that are performed separately from the data editor. They update the DataGridVev directly to show the changes to the user and not to do a re-query. After that, if the user has not made other changes to the table, the form still suggests saving the data, since there are automatically changed columns (although they do not participate in the request texts). It is necessary as that to inform dataset that changes are not present.

Comment: In Delphi there was an opportunity to call ClientDataSet.Merge to merge changes into data

Comment: Update your question with the information in your comment. As I understand, its an UI issue - your view is no longer consistent with your model. You are using windows forms, and a DataGridView Component? Show the code relating to this, preferably a [mcve]